# A new mount point after every reboot

Tags: linux, systemd, arch-arm

I have a Raspberry Pi with Arch Linux and Kodi. I tried to make all config by the new ways of Systemd, that is, by creating Systemd units. For instance, instead of configuring the mount points at boot with the */etc/fstab* file, I did it by `.mount` units.

I made the automounting config with Udisks2 and Polkit.

When I don't unplug the HDD and order the system to reboot, I see that the HDD is mounted in a new directory under */media* after every boot. For instance, suppose that before rebooting the HDD was mounted on */media/Untitled*. After rebooting it will be (auto)mounted on */media/Untitled1*. The next time under */media/Untitled2* and so on. I want it to be mounted always on */media/Untitled*.

Maybe, the solution is [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev), but I don't know.

Edit: I have the following mount units (under */etc/systemd/system* directory):

The boot mount unit (*boot.mount*):

```
# boot.mount
[Unit]
Description=Boot partition

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/<BOOT_PART_UUID>
Where=/boot
Type=vfat
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The root (*/*) mount unit (*-.mount*):

```
# -.mount
[Unit]
Description=Root partition

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/<ROOT_PART_UUID>
Where=/
Type=ext4
Options=noauto,x-systemd.automount

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The home mount unit (*home.mount*):

```
# home.mount
[Unit]
Description=Home partition

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/<HOME_PART_UUID>
Where=/home
Type=ext4
Options=noauto,x-systemd.automount

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The Polkit rules are (under */etc/polkit-1/rules.d* directory):

*50-udisks.rules*

```
// 50-udisks.rules
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    var YES = polkit.Result.YES;
    var permission = {
        //// only required for udisks1:
        //"org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount": YES,
        //"org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount-system-internal": YES,
        //"org.freedesktop.udisks.luks-unlock": YES,
        //"org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-eject": YES,
        //"org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-detach": YES,
        // only required for udisks2:
        "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount": YES,
        "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system": YES,
        "org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock": YES,
        "org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media": YES,
        "org.freedesktop.udisks2.power-off-drive": YES,
        // required for udisks2 if using udiskie from another seat (e.g. systemd):
        "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat": YES,
        "org.freedesktop.udisks2.encrypted-unlock-other-seat": YES,
        "org.freedesktop.udisks2.eject-media-other-seat": YES,
        "org.freedesktop.udisks2.power-off-drive-other-seat": YES
    };
    if (subject.isInGroup("storage")) {
        return permission[action.id];
    }
});
```

(I'm using Udisks2.)

*48-shutdown-power-group.rules*

```
// 48-shutdown-power-group.rules
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.reboot" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions") && subject.isInGroup("power"))
    {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

The udev rules (under */etc/udev/rules.d* directory):

*99-udisks2.rules*

```
# 99-udisks2.rules
# UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED
# ==1: mount filesystem to a shared directory (/media/VolumeName)
# ==0: mount filesystem to a private directory (/run/media/$USER/VolumeName)
# See udisks(8)
ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem|other|crypto", ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="1"
```

Comment: Can you add your .mount units and udisks2 config?